# How to validate JWT token generated from Azure AD B2C in Java?

Tags: java, spring, azure-active-directory, jwt, azure-ad-b2c

I am looking for a code sample in Java to validate the Azure AD B2C token. What are the dependencies we can use? Is JWT token validation steps or code is the same for all the JWT tokens or will it be different? We are not using Spring Security in our project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a ton of libraries [here](https://jwt.io/):

Info. on validating the JWT [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#validating-tokens).

Basically, get the key from the https://.../.well-known/openid-configuration endpoint, check the signature, check expiry, check issuer and audience etc.

Comment: info on b2c custom policies related token validation can be found in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tokens-overview. e.g get the key from urls

Answer (score 0):

Azure B2C JWTs are not spec compliant by default. The jwks_uri may differ for 2 tokens that present the same iss claim. There is an additional claim in these tokens for the policy/user flow used. To get the correct jwks_uri one would need to query the discovery endpoint using this policy/userflow. The jwks_uri response would then be correct and could be used to init a JwtDecoder.