# Azure B2C access token validation and custom JWT token generation

Tags: angular, azure, spring-security, azure-ad-msal, azure-ad-b2c

For a web application in Spring Boot (API REST) ​​+ Angular as front-end we need to integrate with Azure B2C for the authentication part.

I am reading some Microsoft documentation but I have no experience with Azure B2C.

The need would be to validate the Access Token obtained from the Client application (Angular) on Azure and then generate (From Java application) a custom JWT token (ID Token) with user roles and permissions taken from the Database. We can't put the roles on Azure AD.

At this point Client (Angular) and Server (API REST) ​​would only use this token to handle API calls.

What I didn't understand is how to validate the Azure Access Token through the Spring Framework. Which Microsoft web service should be called and how (which library)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer in this question should get you started: [How to validate JWT token generated from Azure AD B2C in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67827731/how-to-validate-jwt-token-generated-from-azure-ad-b2c-in-java)

The AD B2C accesstoken is "just" an oauth2 token, so any library that can validate oauth2 should do it.

Edit (can't comment yet):
I think this link (linked in the other answer) is your best start: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tokens-overview. Anyway, you need a tenant-specific url to get the correct keys, something like https://contoso.b2clogin.com/contoso.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_signupsignin1/discovery/v2.0/keys instead of the generic microsoft keys.

Alternatively you could look at the sample application for java and b2c from microsoft, which uses msal for java: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-java-webapp/tree/master/msal-b2c-web-sample

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In your opinion, can this guide be considered correct as a procedure? The key point seems to me to get the public key for token signing verification from the following URL: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/keys,

Answer (score 0):

Azure B2C JWTs are not spec compliant by default. The jwks_uri may differ for 2 tokens that present the same iss claim. There is an additional claim in these tokens for the policy/user flow used. To get the correct jwks_uri one would need to query the discovery endpoint using this policy/userflow. The jwks_uri response would then be correct and could be used to init a JwtDecoder.
For an issuerUri that looks like this: https://something.b2clogin.com/something.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_signupsignin1/discovery/v2.0/keys
The jwt token will have an issuer that will not include the b2c_1_signupsignin1 bit. This will be in a separate claim. And if you have multiple policies/userflows as such you can configure separate jwks_uri's for them.
What is most confusing is that you can configure B2C to be spec-compliant (meaning the iss claim discovery endpoint returning the same jwks_uri), and then you can indeed use standard libraries.